# passing CustomString& into a constructor won't implicit convert from "string"

Tags: string, optimization, visual-c++, implicit

I can get the compiler (msvc++ express) to convert "string" as a CustomString in a constructor, but not with a reference. Will it therefore not have the same chance of being optimized out with a pass-by-reference anyway, like passing by value with other types can, if the compiler thinks it can?

won't implicit convert using

```
new xmlNode("string")
```

:

```
 xmlNode( CustomString& label )
 {
    this->text = label;
 }
```

will :

```
 xmlNode( CustomString label )
 {
    this->text = label;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
xmlNode(const CustomString& label )
{
    this->text = label;
}
```